# How to send raw data as json in axios?

Tags: javascript, axios

I have created an API call and returns the response using Postman.
The API is with method POST and body as raw (application/json).
[image]

My current axios call is

```
const requestOptions = {
    headers: { 'Content-Type' : 'application/json' },
};
const params = {
    "email": email, 
    "password": password
}

return axios.post(config.apiUrl + 'v1/user/login', params, requestOptions)
```

which is not passing as raw data. What changes should I do in `params` to make this call in raw data as done in the Postman?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can you post the response you get for the axios call?

Comment: Your question doesn't make any sense. "Raw" in Postman terms means "Send this text as the body of the request". You **don't have plain text**, `params` is an object. You'd need JSON and not an object if you wanted to usefully send raw data using Axios. However, Axios *by default* will convert an object into JSON, so the code in the question will have **the same result** as the Postman screenshot without sending "raw" anything.